# How to implement a little static map preview as list icon?

Tags: android, android-widget, google-maps-api-3, android-maps, google-maps-static-api

I built a ListActivity and now I want to add Map Previews as the List Icons. I dont want to extend MapView because: 1st I just need a little static preview and 2nd I already extended to ListView.

I already looked into using the [static map api](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQqwMoBDAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fapis%2Fmaps%2Fdocumentation%2Fstaticmaps%2F&ei=6VmgTPT0GYGmOKfguKQM&usg=AFQjCNEdZcmn2xxERbP4Wen5isuxeUvgbQ&sig2=lYqVrtZcz781XoGH3RS7hQ), however that also doesnt look quite good in that small dimensions:

[image]

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=12&size=65x65&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in Android that generates map previews, sorry. You will need to use some Web service for this.

Comment: I'm also happy with a webservice, but not with a picture filling copyright message. Can somebody suggest me a preview with a smaller copyright message?

Comment: I was using dp-dimensions and forgot that they only count for 320x480 screen devices. But if I download a bigger map image, the copyright data isnt picture filling anymore and still matches 800x480 screen devices. That satisfies me for the moment. Ok, its gonna be downscaled at smaller screens, but thats ok. Maybe I will later decide depending on the screensize which map size I download

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MapView in your layout and use

```
map:liteMode="true"
```

You do not need to extend MapView, just set the above in the layout and you can easily use the view. eg. myMapView.onCreate(), myMapView.getMapAsync() etc.